# Bandwidth & shape average combined

Tags: bandwidth

Here is a class-map that our provider has configured :

```
class ce_ef_output
  police 2600000 
 class ce_af1_output
  police 5360000 
 class class-default
  bandwidth 592
  class class-default
  shape average 8890000
```

How do you explain the "bandwidth 592" with the "shape average 8890000" command ?
Isn't the bandwidth command going to limit traffic at 592 Kbps, and shape average at 8.8 Mbps (let's ignore Bc/Be and potential bursts) ?

How does it make sense to use both at the same time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bandwidth defines the minimum available bandwidth guaranteed during periods of congestion, this means, that if your link is congested and fully utilized, that class will still have reserved 592 Kbps.

Both the shape and police commands restrict the output rate to a maximum Kbps value. Importantly, neither mechanism provides a minimum bandwidth guarantee during periods of congestion.

Without knowing the full policy maps and group policies we can only speculate why they have decided to configure it like this and that is off topic here.

Technically it means, that the default class, typical also know as best effort, has a maximum of 8.8 Mbps with a guaranteed minimum of 592 Kbps.